# One xib, multiple classes without inheritance in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib, nib

I have two classes and one xib. I can't simply use one parent class which will be linked with this xib because it means multiple classes (and of course it is not acceptable for me to insert an object of one parent class into the object/class of the another one).

So is it possible to link multiple classes with one xib if they have the same IBOutlet variables but fully different classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Its not possible to assign multiple classes to one single `XIB`.

Instead create multiple `UIView` & load it on one single `XIB` controller